# Magento 2: in checkout how to display input fields on the same row?

Tags: checkout, blocks, uicomponent, address, field

how can I display **street** , **House number**,  **Addition** fields in one row?
I have this file

> app/code/Mageplaza/Osc/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Mageplaza
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Mageplaza.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 *
 * @category    Mageplaza
 * @package     Mageplaza_Osc
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) Mageplaza (https://www.mageplaza.com/)
 * @license     https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 */

namespace Mageplaza\Osc\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger;
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute;
use Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataDataProvider;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Options;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\AttributeMapper;
use Mageplaza\Osc\Helper\Data as OscHelper;

/**
 * Class LayoutProcessor
 * @package Mageplaza\Osc\Block\Checkout
 */
class LayoutProcessor implements LayoutProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var OscHelper
     */
    private $_oscHelper;

    /**
     * @var AttributeMetadataDataProvider
     */
    private $attributeMetadataDataProvider;

    /**
     * @var AttributeMapper
     */
    protected $attributeMapper;

    /**
     * @var AttributeMerger
     */
    protected $merger;

    /**
     * @var Options
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * @type CheckoutSession
     */
    private $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * LayoutProcessor constructor.
     *
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     * @param OscHelper $oscHelper
     * @param AttributeMetadataDataProvider $attributeMetadataDataProvider
     * @param AttributeMapper $attributeMapper
     * @param AttributeMerger $merger
     */
    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        OscHelper $oscHelper,
        AttributeMetadataDataProvider $attributeMetadataDataProvider,
        AttributeMapper $attributeMapper,
        AttributeMerger $merger
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_oscHelper = $oscHelper;
        $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider = $attributeMetadataDataProvider;
        $this->attributeMapper = $attributeMapper;
        $this->merger = $merger;
    }

    /**
     * Process js Layout of block
     *
     * @param array $jsLayout
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        if (!$this->_oscHelper->isOscPage()) {
            return $jsLayout;
        }

        /** Shipping address fields */
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'])) {
            $fields = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']
            ['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']
            ['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']
                = $this->getAddressFieldset($fields, 'shippingAddress');

            if ($this->_oscHelper->isEnableAmazonPay()) {
                $shippingConfig = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress'];
                $shippingConfig['component'] = 'Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/shipping';
                $shippingConfig['children']['customer-email']['component'] = 'Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/form/element/email';
            }

            /** Fix the issue of the unsaved vat_id field */
            if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
                ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['taxvat'])) {
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
                ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['taxvat']['dataScope'] = 'shippingAddress.vat_id';
            }
        }

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
            //'label' => __('Address'),
            'required' => false, //turn false because I removed main label
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 3,
            'type' => 'group',
            'children' => [
                [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '0',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_length" => 1, "max_text_length" => 24],
                    'additionalClasses' => 'additional',
                    'label' => __('Street'),
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => true
                ],
                [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '0',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "validate-number" => true, "min_text_length" => 1, "max_text_length" => 8],
                    'label' => __('House number'),
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => true

                ],
                [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '0',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "max_text_length" => 9],
                    'label' => __('Addition'),
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => true
                    ]
                ]

        ];

        /** Billing address fields */
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['billingAddress']['children']['billing-address-fieldset']['children'])) {
            $fields = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['billingAddress']
            ['children']['billing-address-fieldset']['children'];
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['billingAddress']
            ['children']['billing-address-fieldset']['children']
                = $this->getAddressFieldset($fields, 'billingAddress');

            /** Fix the issue of the unsaved vat_id field */
            if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['billingAddress']
                ['children']['billing-address-fieldset']['children']['taxvat'])) {
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['billingAddress']
                ['children']['billing-address-fieldset']['children']['taxvat']['dataScope'] = 'billingAddress.vat_id';
            }
        }

        /** Remove billing customer email if quote is not virtual */
        if (!$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
            unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['billingAddress']
                ['children']['customer-email']);
        }

        /** Remove billing address in payment method content */
        $fields = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
        ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];
        foreach ($fields as $code => $field) {
            if ($field['component'] === 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address') {
                unset($fields[$code]);
            }
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Get address fieldset for shipping/billing address
     *
     * @param $fields
     * @param $type
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getAddressFieldset($fields, $type)
    {
        $elements = $this->getAddressAttributes();

        $systemAttribute = $elements['default'];
        if (sizeof($systemAttribute)) {
            $attributesToConvert = [
                'prefix' => [$this->getOptions(), 'getNamePrefixOptions'],
                'suffix' => [$this->getOptions(), 'getNameSuffixOptions'],
            ];
            $systemAttribute = $this->convertElementsToSelect($systemAttribute, $attributesToConvert);
            $fields = $this->merger->merge(
                $systemAttribute,
                'checkoutProvider',
                $type,
                $fields
            );
        }

        $customAttribute = $elements['custom'];
        if (sizeof($customAttribute)) {
            $fields = $this->merger->merge(
                $customAttribute,
                'checkoutProvider',
                $type . '.custom_attributes',
                $fields
            );
        }

        $this->addCustomerAttribute($fields, $type);
        $this->addAddressOption($fields);

        return $fields;
    }

    /**
     * Add customer attribute like gender, dob, taxvat
     *
     * @param $fields
     * @param $type
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    private function addCustomerAttribute(&$fields, $type)
    {
        $attributes = $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider->loadAttributesCollection(
            'customer',
            'customer_account_create'
        );
        $addressElements = [];
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if (!$this->_oscHelper->getAddressHelper()->isCustomerAttributeVisible($attribute)) {
                continue;
            }
            $addressElements[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $this->attributeMapper->map($attribute);
        }

        if (sizeof($addressElements)) {
            $fields = $this->merger->merge(
                $addressElements,
                'checkoutProvider',
                $type . '.custom_attributes',
                $fields
            );
        }

        foreach ($fields as $code => &$field) {
            if (isset($field['label'])) {
                $field['label'] = __($field['label']);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $fields
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    private function addAddressOption(&$fields)
    {
        $fieldPosition = $this->_oscHelper->getAddressHelper()->getAddressFieldPosition();

        $oscField = [];
        $allFieldSection = $this->_oscHelper->getAddressHelper()->getSortedField(false);
        foreach ($allFieldSection as $allfield) {
            /** @var Attribute $field */
            foreach ($allfield as $field) {
                $oscField[] = $field->getAttributeCode();
            }
        }

        $this->rewriteFieldStreet($fields);

        foreach ($fields as $code => &$field) {
            $fieldConfig = isset($fieldPosition[$code]) ? $fieldPosition[$code] : [];
            if (!sizeof($fieldConfig)) {
                if (in_array($code, ['country_id'])) {
                    $field['config']['additionalClasses'] = "mp-hidden";
                    continue;
                } elseif (in_array($code, $oscField)) {
                    unset($fields[$code]);
                }
            } else {
                $oriClasses = isset($field['config']['additionalClasses']) ? $field['config']['additionalClasses'] : '';
                $field['config']['additionalClasses'] = "{$oriClasses} col-mp mp-{$fieldConfig['colspan']}" . ($fieldConfig['isNewRow'] ? ' mp-clear' : '');
                $field['sortOrder'] = (isset($field['sortOrder']) && !in_array(
                    $code,
                    $oscField
                )) ? $field['sortOrder'] : $fieldConfig['sortOrder'];
                if ($code === 'dob') {
                    $field['options'] = ['yearRange'   => '-120y:c+nn',
                                         'maxDate'     => '-1d',
                                         'changeMonth' => true,
                                         'changeYear'  => true
                    ];
                    $field['component'] = 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date';
                }

                $this->rewriteTemplate($field);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Compatible Amazon Pay
         */
        if ($this->_oscHelper->isEnableAmazonPay()) {
            $amazonHelper = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get("Amazon\Core\Helper\Data");
            if ($amazonHelper->isPwaEnabled()) {
                $fields['inline-form-manipulator'] = [
                    'component' => 'Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/amazon'
                ];
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Change template to remove valueUpdate = 'keyup'
     *
     * @param $field
     * @param string $template
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function rewriteTemplate(&$field, $template = 'Mageplaza_Osc/container/form/element/input')
    {
        if (isset($field['type']) && $field['type'] === 'group') {
            foreach ($field['children'] as $key => &$child) {
                if ($key == 0 &&
                    in_array('street', explode('.', $field['dataScope'])) &&
                    $this->_oscHelper->isGoogleHttps()
                ) {
                    $this->rewriteTemplate($child, 'Mageplaza_Osc/container/form/element/street');
                    continue;
                }
                $this->rewriteTemplate($child);
            }
        } elseif (isset($field['config']['elementTmpl']) && $field['config']['elementTmpl'] === "ui/form/element/input") {
            $field['config']['elementTmpl'] = $template;
            if ($this->_oscHelper->isUsedMaterialDesign()) {
                $field['config']['template'] = 'Mageplaza_Osc/container/form/field';
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Change template street when enable material design
     *
     * @param $fields
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function rewriteFieldStreet(&$fields)
    {
        if ($this->_oscHelper->isUsedMaterialDesign()) {
            $fields['country_id']['config']['template'] = 'Mageplaza_Osc/container/form/field';
            $fields['region_id']['config']['template'] = 'Mageplaza_Osc/container/form/field';
            foreach ($fields['street']['children'] as $key => $value) {
                $fields['street']['children'][0]['label'] = $fields['street']['label'];
                $fields['street']['children'][$key]['config']['template'] = 'Mageplaza_Osc/container/form/field';
            }
            $fields['street']['config']['fieldTemplate'] = 'Mageplaza_Osc/container/form/field';
            unset($fields['street']['label']);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Options
     */
    private function getOptions()
    {
        if (!is_object($this->options)) {
            $this->options = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Options::class);
        }

        return $this->options;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    private function getAddressAttributes()
    {
        $attributes = $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider->loadAttributesCollection(
            'customer_address',
            'customer_register_address'
        );

        $elements = [
            'custom'  => [],
            'default' => []
        ];
        /** @var Attribute $attribute */
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($this->_oscHelper->isEnableCustomerAttributes() && $attribute->getIsUserDefined()) {
                continue;
            }

            $code = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            $element = $this->attributeMapper->map($attribute);
            if (isset($element['label'])) {
                $label = $element['label'];
                $element['label'] = __($label);
            }
            (
            $attribute->getIsUserDefined()
            ) ?
                $elements['custom'][$code] = $element :
                $elements['default'][$code] = $element;
        }

        return $elements;
    }

    /**
     * Convert elements(like prefix and suffix) from inputs to selects when necessary
     *
     * @param array $elements address attributes
     * @param array $attributesToConvert fields and their callbacks
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function convertElementsToSelect($elements, $attributesToConvert)
    {
        $codes = array_keys($attributesToConvert);
        foreach (array_keys($elements) as $code) {
            if (!in_array($code, $codes)) {
                continue;
            }
            $options = call_user_func($attributesToConvert[$code]);
            if (!is_array($options)) {
                continue;
            }
            $elements[$code]['dataType'] = 'select';
            $elements[$code]['formElement'] = 'select';

            foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
                $elements[$code]['options'][] = [
                    'value' => $key,
                    'label' => $value,
                ];
            }
        }

        return $elements;
    }
}
```

and it display like below image.[image]

BUT I NEED LIKE BELOW IMAGES:
[image]

Comment: with css you can archive it no need to change in php files unless it is required

Comment: is there any way to achieve through code...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 custom field like this [image]

You should contact Mageplaza for help.